# How can I handle data filtering on a button click on D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I have a D3.js chart I am working on and it works perfectly fine. However, I am trying to add buttons on my main html to handle data filter. These buttons are handled externally. I can't seem to figure out the best way to handle that functionality to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the source code.

On a click event for "Popular," I would like the nodes to show up that has a value of more than 5. In Marvel.json, I have a popularity property with values. When I click on All, it should show all the data.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marvel Characters | Force layout with images</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style>
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,600);
      body {font-family: "Source Code Pro", Consolas, monaco, monospace; line-height: 160%; font-size: 16px;  margin: 0; }
      path.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
      .node:not(:hover) .nodetext {
        display: none;
      }
      h1 { font-size: 36px; margin: 10px 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: normal;}
      h2, h3 { font-size: 18px; margin: 5px 0 ; font-weight: normal;}
      header {padding: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
      a:link { color: #EE3124; text-decoration: none;}
      a:visited { color: #EE3124; }
      a:hover { color: #A4CD39; text-decoration: underline;}
      a:active { color: #EE3124; }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <header>
<!-- D3 BUTTONS -->
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button1 active">All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button3">Popular</button>
  </div>
      <h1>Marvel Characters</h1>
      <h2>Click to view their identity</h2>
      <h3>And link to their web page!</h3>
    </header>
    <!-- container for force layout visualisation  -->
    <section id="vis"></section> 
<script>

// some colour variables
  var tcBlack = "#130C0E";

// rest of vars
var w = 960,
    h = 800,
    maxNodeSize = 50,
    x_browser = 20,
    y_browser = 25,
    root;

var vis;
var force = d3.layout.force(); 

vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

d3.json("marvel.json", function(json) {

  root = json;
  root.fixed = true;
  root.x = w / 2;
  root.y = h / 4;


        // Build the path
  var defs = vis.insert("svg:defs")
      .data(["end"]);


  defs.enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

     update();
});


/**
 *   
 */
function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .linkStrength(function(l, i) {return 1; })
    .size([w, h])
    .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

   var path = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    path.enter().insert("svg:path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      // .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
      .style("stroke", "#eee");


  // Exit any old paths.
  path.exit().remove();



  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });


  // Enter any new nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  // Append a circle
  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", "#eee");


  // Append images
  var images = nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.img;})
        .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", 50);

  // make the image grow a little on mouse over and add the text details on click
  var setEvents = images
          // Append hero text
          .on( 'click', function (d) {
              d3.select("h1").html(d.hero); 
              d3.select("h2").html(d.name); 
              d3.select("h3").html ("Take me to " + "<a href='" + d.link + "' >"  + d.hero + " web page ⇢"+ "</a>" ); 
           })

          .on( 'mouseenter', function() {
            // select element in current context
            d3.select( this )
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) { return -60;})
              .attr("y", function(d) { return -60;})
              .attr("height", 100)
              .attr("width", 100);
          })
          // set back
          .on( 'mouseleave', function() {
            d3.select( this )
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
              .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
              .attr("height", 50)
              .attr("width", 50);
          });

  // Append hero name on roll over next to the node as well
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("class", "nodetext")
      .attr("x", x_browser)
      .attr("y", y_browser +15)
      .attr("fill", tcBlack)
      .text(function(d) { return d.hero; });


  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();


  // Re-select for update.
  path = vis.selectAll("path.link");
  node = vis.selectAll("g.node");

function tick() {


    path.attr("d", function(d) {

     var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
           dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
           dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
           return   "M" + d.source.x + "," 
            + d.source.y 
            + "A" + dr + "," 
            + dr + " 0 0,1 " 
            + d.target.x + "," 
            + d.target.y;
  });
    node.attr("transform", nodeTransform);    
  }
}


/**
 * Gives the coordinates of the border for keeping the nodes inside a frame
 * http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492
 */ 
function nodeTransform(d) {
  d.x =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(w - (d.imgwidth/2 || 16), d.x));
    d.y =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(h - (d.imgheight/2 || 16), d.y));
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   }

/**
 * Toggle children on click.
 */ 
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update();
}


/**
 * Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
 */ 
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = []; 
  var i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) 
      node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) 
      node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
} 


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**marvel.json**

```
{
 "name": "marvel",
 "img": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/marvel.png",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Heroes",
   "children": [
    {
      "hero": "Spider-Man",
      "name": "Peter Benjamin Parker", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/54/spider-man",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_spiderman.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 1
    },
    {
      "hero": "CAPTAIN MARVEL",
      "name": "Carol Danvers", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/9/captain_marvel",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainmarvel.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 3
    },
    {
      "hero": "HULK", 
      "name": "Robert Bruce Banner",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/25/hulk",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_hulk.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 6
    },
    {
      "hero": "Black Widow", 
      "name": "Natalia 'Natasha' Alianovna Romanova",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/6/black_widow",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_blackwidow.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 7
    },
    {
      "hero": "Daredevil", 
      "name": "Matthew Michael Murdock",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/11/daredevil",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_daredevil.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 7
    },
    {
      "hero": "Wolverine", 
      "name": "James Howlett",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/66/wolverine",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_wolverine.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 8
    },
    {
      "hero": "Captain America", 
      "name": "Steven Rogers",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/8/captain_america",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainamerica.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 9
    },
    {
      "hero": "Iron Man", 
      "name": "Anthony Edward 'Tony' Stark",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/29/iron_man",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_ironman.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 4
    },
    {
      "hero": "THOR", 
      "name": "Thor Odinson",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/60/thor",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_thor.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 5
    }
  ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Villains",
   "children": [
    {
      "hero": "Dr. Doom",
      "name": "Victor von Doom", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/13/dr_doom",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/drdoom.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 6
    },
    {
      "hero": "Mystique",
      "name": "Unrevealed", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1552/mystique",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/mystique.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 8
    },
    {
      "hero": "Red Skull",
      "name": "Johann Shmidt", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1901/red_skull",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/redskull.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 9
    },
    {
      "hero": "Ronan",
      "name": "Ronan", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/49/ronan",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/ronan.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 8
    },
    {
      "hero": "Magneto",
      "name": "Max Eisenhardt", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/35/magneto",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/magneto.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 8
    },
    {
      "hero": "Thanos",
      "name": "Thanos", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/58/thanos",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/thanos.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 7
    },
    {
      "hero": "Black Cat",
      "name": "Felicia Hardy", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/271/black_cat",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/blackcat.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 6
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Teams",
   "children": [
    {
      "hero": "Avengers",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/68/avengers",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/avengers.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 6
    },
    {
      "hero": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/70/guardians_of_the_galaxy",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/gofgalaxy.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 5
    },
    {
      "hero": "Defenders",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/534/defenders",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/defenders.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 2
    },
    {
      "hero": "X-Men",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/71/x-men",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/xmen.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 3
    },
    {
      "hero": "Fantastic Four",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/69/fantastic_four",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/fantasticfour.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 3
    },
    {
      "hero": "Inhumans",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1040/inhumans",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/inhumans.png",
      "size": 40000,
      "popularity": 9
    }
   ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you the .filter() feature of d3.js.
Store the flattened json records in a global variable. Setup an onclick listener for 'all' and 'popular' buttons. The onclick listener for 'popular' button can be something along the lines of:

```
function filterPopular(){
  tempNodes = nodes.filter(function(d){
    return !('popularity' in d) || d.popularity>5;
  });
  update(tempNodes);
}
```

What .filter() esentially does is keep the records which return true for the callback function. In this case records which do not have a popularity field (the non-leaf nodes) or those which have popularity greater than 5 will be retained in tempNodes. I am storing the filtered records into a new var so that the records are maintained globally in case you click the 'all' button. Call update with tempNodes. The nodes will now disappear but links from parent to deleted children will remain. You'll have to figure out a way to remove these links.
Hope this helped at least a little!